# Christian young adult sci-fi series with one book involving a frozen column of time

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, christian

I remember reading a series of young adult (at the time it was called juvenile) science fiction novels in the 1990s with a Christian slant (characters were occasionally seen praying, and so on).

In one of the books (I think it was the third in the series?), one of the characters is involved in an experiment in Colorado that goes horribly awry, creating a column of energy where time inside is frozen. The column also shifts the Earth's axis, wreaking havoc across the globe. One of the other characters essentially has to go into the column and shut the experiment down, causing time to reset to the moment when the column first appeared.

Any help tracking this series down would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Further research suggests it's the ***[Perimeter One](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?6471)*** series by David Ward.

From the Goodreads page for the third book in the series, *[Out of Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2658048-out-of-time)* (1994):

> In the futuristic Perimeter One Adventures, the price of adventure is high, but the Graham family can overcome the toughest challenges, knowing that God prevails in all things. In #3, the Grahams are challenged by time itself in a race against the clock.

Comment: We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours have elapsed since the question was first posted.